# Django - Global name is not defined error

Tags: python, django

I have a `NameError: global name 'CreateMapForm' is not defined` error but **it is intermittent**.

I dont get it because everything seems fine in my python IDE. `CreateMapForm` is just a simple `ModelForm`. Anybody can point to a cause of this problem or suggest where to look for a cause?

maps/views.py:

```
from maps.forms import *

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def createMap(request, folder_id):
    folder = Folder.objects.get(pk=folder_id, created_by=request.user)

    if type(folder) != Folder:
        folder = folder.parent

    nodes = folder.get_ancestors(include_self=True)

    form = CreateMapForm() #this line cause the error
    html = render_to_string("basqui/manage_maps_create.html", {'folder': folder, 'nodes': nodes, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response = json.dumps({'html': html})

    if request.POST:
        form = CreateMapForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.created_by = request.user
            instance.parent = folder
            instance.save()
            response = json.dumps({"map": {"pk": instance.pk, "name": instance.name}}, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        else:
            html = render_to_string("basqui/manage_maps_create.html", {'folder': folder, 'nodes': nodes, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            response = json.dumps({'html': html})

    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")
```

maps/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from maps.models import *

class CreateMapForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BasquiMap
        fields = ('name', 'layers', 'wms')
```

Comment: Have you tried importing `CreateMapForm` (and any other forms you need in your view) explicitly with `from maps.forms import CreateMapForm` rather than `from maps.forms import *`? That should at least move the intermittent error to the import!

Comment: @xnx I tryed it and like you said I have an ImportError, but I dont know why the import is nort working. Have an idea?

Comment: Is the `maps` app in your `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes it is, thats what I have verify first

Comment: A little hard to say what might be wrong, but ensure your `__init__.py` file hasn't gone missing from the app directory, try the import from the Django interactive console (`python manage.py shell`) and make sure you've restarted your web server if you're not using the Django development one. Any maybe post the Exception you're seeing?

Comment: `from maps.forms import *` works in shell and `import maps` and calling `maps.forms.CreateMapForm()` works in the app... im so confuse about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66158/discussion-between-below-the-radar-and-xnx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have `CreateMapForm()` in the `forms` you need to import it in `views` so add the following to `views` :

```
from maps import forms
```

and replace the following :

```
form = CreateMapForm()
```

with :

```
form = forms.CreateMapForm()
```

Comment: hi, sorry for this stupid question, but from maps.forms import * should do it right?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar your welcome yes surely it can do it too!